# Want unchanged HDMI output when lid closed (Linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

My question is similar to [a couple of other questions](https://superuser.com/questions/791382/can-i-continue-using-my-hdmi-output-with-my-laptop-closed) except I need a Linux/Ubuntu solution.

When I plug a HDMI cable into my laptop, I automatically get a second desktop on the second screen. This is what I want. I can play a video on this second desktop, sound and resolution etc are correctly set up automagically.

I close the laptop lid, and the following happens:

- the second desktop ceases to exist,
- the first desktop is redirected to HDMI out,
- the first desktop's resolution changes, which causes VLC to exit full-screen mode.

What I want when I close the lid:

- the first desktop to remain attached to the laptop screen, which is now off,
- the second desktop to remain on the HDMI output.

Basically, Ubuntu is trying to privilege my "primary" desktop and keep outputting it to whichever device is available. I want a non-invasive setup whereby closing the laptop lid doesn't change any of the outputs.

How do I do this? Thanks.